# Log closed tcp connections with iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, tcp

I can easily log new tcp connections with iptables like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport XYZ -m state --state NEW -j LOG
```

Is there a way to log when a connection is closed?

Comment: The command didn't work for me until I changed `-dport` to `--dport`

Comment: Thx, updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be something better, but the tcp protocol ends connections with the FIN or RST packets. You could match on these.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport XYZ --tcp-flags FIN FIN -j LOG
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport XYZ --tcp-flags RST RST -j LOG
```

The FIN is repeated as `--tcp-flags` takes 2 arguments, a mask of what flags to look at, and what combination to accept.

Comment: Seems to work. Thanks. `conntrack` is also useful for this.